# Installation of MySQL 5.7 on Debian 7 Wheezy

Tags: mysql, apt, mysql-5.7

I would like to install MySql 5.7 on Debian 7 Wheezy. I put :

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/   wheezy mysql-5.7
```

in file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
```

Next I run commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And tried install package:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
```

I got an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-community-server' instead of 'mysql-server-5.7'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-common (= 5.7.11-1debian7) but 5.5.47-0+deb7u1 is to be installed
                          Depends: mysql-client (= 5.7.11-1debian7)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Do you have any ideas to resolve this problem?
I also tried:

```
Note, selecting 'mysql-community-server' instead of 'mysql-server-5.7'
```

But it's not the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this post and can confirm simply changing the priority of your cache by downloading the `.deb` package directly from [MySQL Downloads](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/)

Using the command line:

```
$ cd /usr/src && sudo wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
```

> Please note: by convension the /src directory on linux exists for source code to live before being compiled - I believe the deb package above therefore belongs here.

This works for Debian/Wheezy.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
```

Once this you have gone through the steps, you simply hit `Ok`, and then proceed to install `mysql-server` like normal:

```
$ sudo apt-update
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

For me, this resulted in the following:

> [info] MySQL Community Server 5.7.14 is started.
>   Setting up mysql-server (5.7.14-1debian7) ...

Further reading, if you ever want to remove this package, you can do so:

```
$ cd /usr/src && sudo dpkg --remove http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Need to run `apt-get update` before `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020 with Debian Wheezy 7.11 the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920943) doesn't work anymore. I had to change a few things and thought it might be useful to share the result:

Install `mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb` (Version 0.8.15-1_all won't work: dpkg can't handle the `"control.tar.xz"` it contains.)

```sh
cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

This will create the necessary `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` file.

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Thanks goes to [David Kehr](https://www.davidkehr.com/mysql-5-5-auf-5-7-in-debian-aktualisieren/) from where I got the working mysql-apt-config version.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to specify the version in the apt-get command, just type :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

After the install, you can type the following command to check mysql version

```
aptitude show mysql-server
```

On my machine I have the following result :

```
...
Version : 5.7.13-1debian7
...
```

Comment: Very stupid answer... I've resolved this issue - I had to change pin priority of mysql packages. You have to specify version which you want to install, if it is different than your default version in apt-cache policy (in this case it's not clean debian, but modified version, so apt sources are slightly different, pins etc.).